# BackgroundWorker froze UI after finishing task

Tags: c#, winforms

Background worker froze UI while it finishes doing task. I had before problem with MessageBox not closing (i had it in RunWorkerCompleted), when I deleted it, program started frozing and cpu usage is going to 15%.

```
        public Admin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DateTime newDate;
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            newDate = now.AddDays(-7);
            var pathWithEnv = @"%userprofile%\Desktop\Zlecenia_Lavello\Spakowane_zlecenia_" + newDate.ToShortDateString() + "-" + now.ToShortDateString() + ".xlsx";
            var filePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(pathWithEnv);
            if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy && !File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
            bool isLastDayOfTheMonth = (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday);
            ExportLastMonth(isLastDayOfTheMonth);
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
            bool isLastDayOfTheMonth = (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday);
            while (isLastDayOfTheMonth == true)
            {

            }
        }
        void ExportLastMonth(bool isLast)
        {
            if (isLast == true)
            {
                DateTime newDate;
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                newDate = now.AddDays(-7);
                var pathWithEnv = @"%userprofile%\Desktop\Zlecenia_Lavello\Spakowane_zlecenia_" + newDate.ToShortDateString() + "-" + now.ToShortDateString() + ".xlsx";
                var filePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(pathWithEnv);
                if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    using MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring);
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("ALTER TABLE spakowane_zlecenia DROP id_zlecenia;ALTER TABLE historia_zlecen DROP id_zlecenia;INSERT INTO historia_zlecen SELECT * FROM spakowane_zlecenia; SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data_zlecenia, '%d.%m.%Y') as DATA, numer_zlecenia as NUMER, model as MODEL, uszkodzony as USZKODZONY, pracownik_odlewnia as ODLEWNIA, pracownik_szlifiernia as SZLIFIERNIA, pracownik_kontrolajakosci as 'KONTROLA JAKOSCI', pracownik_pakowanie as PAKOWANIE, etap_odlewnia as START, etap_pakowanie_end as KONIEC FROM spakowane_zlecenia;ALTER TABLE historia_zlecen ADD id_zlecenia int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;ALTER TABLE spakowane_zlecenia ADD id_zlecenia int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;", conn))
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        using MySqlDataAdapter sqlda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        using DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        sqlda.Fill(dt);

                        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
                        {
                            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Arkusz1");
                            wb.SaveAs(filePath);
                            using MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("TRUNCATE spakowane_zlecenia;ALTER TABLE spakowane_zlecenia DROP id_zlecenia;ALTER TABLE spakowane_zlecenia ADD id_zlecenia int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;", conn);
                            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I want it to export while program starts and do nothing on next run when file is already created.

Comment: Yeah but the good news is it'll only jam up on Mondays

Comment: @CaiusJard not gonna lie, that's good point

Comment: The downside of things that work everyday but Monday is that you might write it on a Tuesday, test and debug it on a Wednesday, put it through it's QA paces on the Thursday and deploy it late Friday afternoon.  Then, when you get to work first thing Monday morning, you'll be amazed at how many users notice.

Comment: @Flydog57 it's just exporting data from database to excel, and im testing it by changing system date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct this part:

```
        bool isLastDayOfTheMonth = (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday);
        while (isLastDayOfTheMonth == true)
        {

        }
```

It loops forever every Monday

---

By the way, if you have a bool, such as `isLastDayOfTheMonth` you don't need to compare it to another bool to realize a bool result

```
if(isLastDayOfTheMonth == true)
```

Is identical to

```
if(isLastDayOfTheMonth)
```